# ASP.NET - Browser speed on localhost

Tags: asp.net

When I browse the asp.net pages on local host, only IE renders pages very fast. In every other browser I have a delay of 1 second or so. Why is that happening and is there any way to speed up the response time in other browsers (web.config, IIS setting)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. The delay is down to Vista/Win7's new tcp/ip stack, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

This usually does the trick for FireFox:

http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/disable-ipv6-in-firefox-3/

I can't recall whether or not I've encountered this in any other browser but Firefox. If you are experiencing this problem on other browsers as well, you can also explicitly map localhost to 127.0.0.1 in your host file (if you are running Windows).

From what I can tell, the browser is trying to externally resolve "localhost" for every request (images, CSS, scripts included). This can trash performance because this lookup fails/times out.